# How to map inherited class using Mapster

Tags: c#, mapping, mapster

I would like to map between two classes by using the following statements:

```
var directoryDataModel = new DirectoryDM()
{
    Title = "School Directory",
    Persons = new List<PersonDM>()
    {
        new TeacherDM() { Name = "Johnson", Department = "Math" },
        new StudentDM() { Name = "Billy", Classes = new List<string>() { "Math", "Physics" } }
    }                
};
var directoryViewModel = directoryDataModel.Adapt<DirectoryVM>();
var directoryDataModel2 = directoryViewModel.Adapt<DirectoryDM>();
```

What do I need to do so that it handles the mapping of the derived classes in the Persons list?

TeacherVM <=> TeacherDM and StudentVM <=> StudentDM

Data Model:

```
public class DirectoryDM
{
    public string Title;
    public List<PersonDM> Persons;
}
public class PersonDM
{
    public string Name;
}
public class TeacherDM : PersonDM
{
    public string Department;
}
public class StudentDM : PersonDM
{
    public List<string> Classes;
}
```

View Model:

```
public class DirectoryVM
{
    public string Title;
    public List<PersonVM> Persons;
    public bool AdditionalStuff;
}
public class PersonVM
{
    public string Name;
    public bool AdditionalStuff;
}
public class TeacherVM : PersonVM
{
    public string Department;
    public bool AdditionalStuff2;
}
public class StudentVM : PersonVM
{
    public List<string> Classes;
    public bool AdditionalStuff2;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has to be done everytime... or just once... but here is how to organice the "configs" for this model.

```
            TypeAdapterConfig<PersonDM, PersonVM>.NewConfig()
                .Include<TeacherDM, TeacherVM>()
                .Include<StudentDM, StudenVM>();

            var viewModel = dataModel.Adapt<FlexSortVM>();
```

and

```
            TypeAdapterConfig<PersonVM, PersonDM>.NewConfig()
                .Include<TeacherVM, TeacherDM>()
                .Include<StudentVM, StudenDM>();

            var dataModel = viewModel.Adapt<FlexSortDM>();
```